# Solr server HttpParse error

Tags: solr, jetty, solrcloud

Hi when i am sending a query to solr server using http client , solr server prints exception log saying HttpParser full.

I am running solrcloud 4.0 in jetty server.
Is this a problem with jetty ?

What could be the reason for this and how can i resolve it ?

Comment: I have tried same query with solrj client,CloudSolrServer, it works fine.But HttpClient still fails

Comment: Are you sending a really large query that might be filling up the request buffer?  A stack trace would help to know more.

Comment: my query is too large to be posted here,but i can explain,i am looking for a 600 project ids from solr,thats it, so q=proj1+proj2+pro3+proj4...proj600.The question is same query works with cloud server client and fails with HttpClient.Server prints this:2013-04-15 10:15:22.600:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:Full [1160919745,-1,m=4,g=6144,p=6144,c=6144]={2F736F6C722F70726F6A656374732F73656C6563743F713D696425334125323850524F4A35333135392B50524F4A35343032362B50524F4A35323631382B50524F4A353.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are producing a url that is too long for the jetty buffer default size.

- Jetty 6 - http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+Connectors
- Jetty 7,8 - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Connectors
- Jetty 9 - http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html#jetty-connectors-http-configuration

Comment: Jesse, any idea about why it was working with solrj client ? My guess is solrj client sends request in multipart (thats what i learned from solrj source)